# COUNT with subquery fail on H2 database with "Duplicate column name"

Tags: sql, h2

we aware strange behavior of H2 when querying COUNT with a subquery.

Prepare table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fieldName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
);
```

Test simple query (works fine):

```
SELECT F1.id, F2.id from Foo as F1 INNER JOIN Foo F2 on F1.id = F2.id
```

Test same query with count:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT F1.id, F2.id from Foo as F1 INNER JOIN Foo F2 on F1.id = F2.id
) q;
```

Got following error:

> [42S21][42121] Duplicate column name "ID"; SQL statement:
>       select count(*) FROM (

Any workarounds?

**UPDATED:**
The problem was in that original table name erased when preparing subquery column names and in fact I have :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT id, id from q
);
```

Adding alias (as mentioned by [Abdul Rasheed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5366015/abdul-rasheed)) fix the problem.

Comment: both column F1.id, F2.id have name is id, so u hv to use alias. eg SELECT F1.id as id1, F2.id as id2 ...

Comment: That join makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why to use the same field and the same table with aliases.
Why don't you use simply a query like that :

```
SELECT count(id) FROM Foo
```

Comment: It's just simplified example. Same issue with:
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT F1.id, F2.id from Foo1 as F1 INNER JOIN Foo2 F2 on F1.id = F2.id
) q;

Answer (score 0):

This problem isn't stricly H2 related, but happens in all SQL databases. A top-level SQL `SELECT` statement is allowed to project two columns by the same name, but a subquery - in particular a derived table - is not. This is irrespective of the fact whether the ambiguous column name from the subquery is ever referenced.

The solution is to explicitly alias your columns:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT f1.id AS f1_id, f2.id AS f2_id 
  FROM foo AS f1 
  INNER JOIN foo f2 ON f1.id = f2.id
) q;
```

Or to avoid the projection in the derived table entirely, as you're not going to need it to calculate the count value:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT 1
  FROM foo AS f1 
  INNER JOIN foo f2 ON f1.id = f2.id
) q;
```

At this point, you could obviously just avoid the derived table completely:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM foo AS f1 
INNER JOIN foo f2 ON f1.id = f2.id;
```

An alternative when using H2 1.4.198 or later is to use window functions to calculate the count value on each row:

```
SELECT f1.id AS f1_id, f2.id AS f2_id, count(*) OVER ()
FROM foo AS f1 
INNER JOIN foo f2 ON f1.id = f2.id
```