# H2: Duplicate column names in count query with nested query

Tags: java, sql, database, h2, jooq

I'm wondering whether is possible to keep table names in a nested query to avoid the `Duplicate column name` error.

As a minimal example, I have the following tables:

- CUSTOMERS: ID, NAME, CITY_ID
- CITIES: ID, NAME, ZIP

The following query fails with the error `Duplicate column name "NAME"`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT CUSTOMERS.NAME, CITY.NAME 
  FROM CUSTOMERS JOIN CITIES ON CUSTOMERS.CITY_ID = CITIES.ID
)
```

Apparently H2 strips table names in the nested query, thus resulting in two columns named `NAME`
(see [COUNT with subquery fail on H2 database with "Duplicate column name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282769/count-with-subquery-fail-on-h2-database-with-duplicate-column-name)).

A solution would be using column alias in the nested query, but I'd like to avoid it due to other project requirements (i.e., I'd like to use column identifiers generated with Jooq to build queries).

Do you know a way to force H2 to keep table names in the nested query?

Comment: How do you create the jOOQ query?

Comment: @LukasEder We use the Jooq DSL to build the query, and then we use `dsl.fetchCount(query)` to count the rows returned by `query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

This is a known jOOQ issue, specific to the usage of [`DSLContext.fetchCount(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchCount-org.jooq.Select-): https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7867

It has nothing to do with H2, but happens with all databases, as all databases allow for duplicate column names in top level selects, but not in derived tables.

jOOQ should disambiguate your column names as follows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT CUSTOMERS.NAME AS C1, CITY.NAME AS C2
  FROM CUSTOMERS JOIN CITIES ON CUSTOMERS.CITY_ID = CITIES.ID
)
```

But this is tricky as the columns might be referenced from an `ORDER BY` clause (which might be required because of a `LIMIT` / `FETCH` clause), so the issue hasn't been solved yet.

#### Workarounds

You will have to work around this yourself. You have 3 options:

- Rewrite the query when running a count, or rewrite it in general using column aliases
- Run an ordinary count query, manually
- In H2 1.4.198 (not yet released as of today), window functions will be implemented, so you could project the `COUNT(*) OVER ()` expression to calculate the count value on each row.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas.

We implemented option 1, creating a view with unambigous column names and then querying the view.